# How do i find the number of items in a list in drupal?

Tags: json, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

Im trying to make a JSON view in drupal 7 for a web service.
the format they want is

```
stories={
  numberOfItemsOnPage:
  totalItemsInList
  listOfItems:[
     id
     title
     date
     author
  ]
}
```

I cannot find any field in the views datasource module that allows me to put the count into the json?  I can write a custom module if need be but I would need help with where to start.  I'm very new to drupal any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check header and footer options. Global: Result summary can do things like "Displaying start - end of total". I don't know how views datasource module works, but I guess that's the right place to start searching how to do it.

Comment: there is a option in the header but it doesnt seem to be working.  I dont know how to find it for my json object